# Is there any reason to use pipeline with reactiveRedisTemplate?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-webflux, pipeline, reactive

now I'm using Spring Webflux with Redis.
Since i use Webflux, i chose ReactiveRedisTemplate to use on non-blocking system properly.

After using ReactiveRedisTemplate, i just think of how i can improve redis performance in my project. And i find out using pipeline is the one way.

But ReactiveRedisTemplate only provide execute() method to use pipeline and it ignore the result of redis action. I don't know i perfectly undestand, i think it's only for CUD, not READ.

So, there are several questions.

1. Why doesn't ReactiveRedisTemplate provide pipeline for READ?
2. Webflux choose parallel threading model to improve the performance. so I think Redis pipeline sometimes is not the best way. Because the big reason to use pipeline is to decrease RTT.
   so Why does ReactiveRedisTemplate provide pipeline for CUD(as i understand, execute())?

I tried execute() method

```
    public Mono<Long> unlinkInPipeline(Flux<String> values) {
        return reactiveRedisTemplate.execute(connection ->
                        values.flatMap(id -> {
                                    return Flux.just(ByteBuffer.wrap(getKey(id).getBytes()));
                                })
                                .flatMap(buffer -> connection.keyCommands().unlink(buffer)), false)
                .reduce(Long::sum)
                .defaultIfEmpty(0L);
    }
```